How do I add an obstacle avoidance constraint to the GCS problem in drake?
I am using the GCSTrajectoryOptimization class in the drake simulator. I am using the GCS base as a map to navigate through. I would like to add a constraint to the class that encourages the optimizer to avoid coming too close to an edge of the open space.
I know the planner will only travel through free space, but I would like it to consider the size of a vehicle. I have thought about seperately remembering where all the obstacles are and encoding a constraint to keep the decision points away from every obstacle, but that would be very expensive. I have also thought about shrinking the size of each polygon, but that will also affect the search space which I would like to avoid, if possible.
This can be solved with a local planner in addition to the GCS planner, but I would rather the GCS planner include a simple obstacle avoidance model.
Any thoughts?

How are you generating the regions? Are you using Iris? Or IrisInConfigurationSpace?
The most elegant answer is to add the vehicle geometry in the IRIS step. If you want additional padding as a hard constraint, then again I would add this at the IRIS step.
We do sometimes add collision avoidance costs/constraints in the GCSTrajOpt, but only if there is a good reason to not do them in IRIS.

I am not currently using IRIS. As an input to my planner, I have a terrain map (defined by convex sets for each terrain class in an area) with several terrain types including obstacles. I use the terrain map when defining the cost for each vertex when traveling across the map (a road is easier to travel along than not traveling along a road, etc.) -> distance across vertex * terrain cost = vertex cost. I have not studied IRIS, so I am not sure if IRIS includes the capability to encode terrain classes into the convex sets other than "obstacle" and "not obstacle".

IrisInConfigurationSpace is the general tool for computing configuration-space regions with avoid collisions with task-space geometry mapped through the kinematics. You're right that it doesn't support terrain/height maps directly. I guess to use it, you would need to make simple collision geometry out of the regions... e.g. using something like VPolytope::WriteObj.
